# Email verification feature in wordpress social login plugin

Tags: plugin-development, social-connect, email-verification, oauth

I'm using [wordpress social login plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-social-login/)..   It uses [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) library.

[Here is a demo](http://oyanix.com/opensource/hybridauth/) of HybridAuth library.

The wordpress plugin looks nice. But it generates a random email for most of the social sites.

This plugin doesn't offer email verification for the sites which doesn't offer verified email address.

I mean the plugin says

> Currently only Facebook, Google, Yahoo and Foursquare do provide the
>   verified user email

So for other sites it generates a random email address.
This is the code which generates random email

```
// generate an email if none
        if ( ! isset ( $user_email ) OR ! is_email( $user_email ) ){
            $user_email = strtolower( $provider . "_user_" . $user_login ) . "@example.com";
        }

        // email should be unique
        if ( email_exists ( $user_email ) ){
            do
            {
                $user_email = md5(uniqid(wp_rand(10000,99000)))."@example.com";
            } while( email_exists( $user_email ) );
        }
```

I want all my accounts in my sites to be verified. So instead of generating random email I need a function that popup a form by asking the user to fill his/her email address.

And then when a user click submit it should send a confirmation link or randomly generated password to their email.

Can anyone help me to implement this.? [Here is the full code](https://github.com/hybridauth/WordPress-Social-Login/blob/master/includes/plugin.auth.php) which process the signup/login

Answer (score -1):

We at [LoginRadius](http://www.loginradius.com) also provide social login, but as far as I know only Twitter does not provider email address while every other social networks do. I can't help you much here, but Try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/loginradius-for-wordpress/) - it opens a pop-up asking users to enter their email address if its not supplied.